# Exposing a stream or using the observer pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a class as follows

```
class Controller {
    Stream<Requests> stream;
}
```

and other listener classes that want to know about requests from the stream and act according to them.

I wanted to know what is better in terms of OO principles:

1. exposing the stream and letting listener classes listen to it
2. Adding listener classes as observers and notifying them when a new request arises from the stream?
3. maybe a different solution that i didn't mention here?

I don't think it matters but I am using dart, question probably applies to any oo language.

Comment: One class does not make OO. You need to identify relationships and collaboration, responsibilities, subsystems, etc. You have only ONE class that only holds a stream. Nobody can claim to be able to give OO advice based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Streams work by pushing the data from the producer to the consumer as it becomes available (at least in Java, not sure how streams are implemented in dart). So you sort of get a push observer out of the box if you are using a stream and subscribe to it.

I see no benefit out of adding another observer on top of that (at least in Java).

Note that streams tend to be more from the `functional paradigm` than from the `object oriented` one. I think your first solution is sound from a software design perspective.

Comment: @Eugene could you explain?

Comment: By producer I mean a `Publisher`, as defined here https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.2/README.md

Comment: Who passes the data into Subscriber's `onNext` https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html#onNext-T- ?

Comment: @Eugene since OPs question contained the words `Controller` and `Requests` I think `reactive streams` are the *sensible interpretation* for `stream` in this context (IMHO). My first comment also referenced `reactive streams`.

Comment: if you think so, you should have that *explicit* and drop the confusion, as such you probably make sense, but the truth is now buried in this (now useless, thus I'll remove them) comments